# Mail is sending text attachments rather than including the text inline

Tags: macos

In My Mac Mail, the messages are going as text attachment, rather than just appearing inline as the mail contents.  How can I make sure that the contents of my mails are not being sent as attachments?

Comment: The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly “you don't get”. Especially links to screenshots (maybe annotated) and a more detailed description about what you see/do and what you would expect would help, we love details here.

Comment: We can not help you since we do not understand your question. Please be bit more descriptive like, what message, do you mean you copy a text from a message and paste it in to the mail, but would like to see it as attachment? or clearly distinct from the rest of the text in your email?

Comment: I suspect that it is Windows recipients that are receiving your mail contents as a text attachment?  What happens if you mail yourself? There is an option in preferences somewhere for windows friendly MIME encoding or something (not at a mac to test at the moment)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide an answer (yet) but I think i can clarify the question, as a couple of users in our organisation are experiencing a similar issue. Mail sent from a Mac (Mac OS X Version 10.7.5 Using Mac Mail, via Office 365/ exchange) is appearing as it should when the mail consists of *just* text. However, when there is an attachment added (in the case of my example a word document, but it's been the same for any file type) the email body text does not appear in the recipient's mail program (Outlook 2010 in this case) but IS present as a .htm attachment - as is the signature ad

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and figured out what was going wrong.

In mail, when you copy or drag the attachment, all text below attachment is treated as attachment hence it converts it to attachment and no text goes to the recipient.

All you need to do is in menu bar `Edit > Attachment > Always insert attachment at end of message`.

This will now always copy your attachments to the end and your text will remain safe in email.